# SoundCloud API forbidden resources

Tags: macos, api, soundcloud

Hello I am currently writing a native SoundCloud application for OSX. In order to write that application I need an object oriented wrapper that gives me the SoundCloud data in form of objects. Now I have several questions regarding the api:

1. Users are allowed to forbid access to their songs via third party applications, I guess this a protection to avoid that the songs are downloaded, are there made any exceptions for third party developers?
2. SoundCloud itself is not only using the public api but also some other private api's, am I allowed to use them if I arrange it with you(with the api-team)? (The reason why I am asking that is that the public api is not reflecting all data for example the me/activities endpoint does not reflect the user that reposted a song.)
3. If no, will you allow it in the future?

With private api's I mean endpoints that are hosted under the url `api-v2.soundcloud.com`

Thank you in advance for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Artists can forbid access to tracks for third party apps which was the reason why I didn't get any tracks for the playlist.